# Install a specific gcc version to match the version the kernel was compiled with (I have 11.4.0 need 11.3.0)

Tags: nvidia, gcc

In an effort to fix issues with nvidea graphics where it briefly flickers black (after upgrade), I am trying to install an older driver. However the nvidea driver complains the compiler version used to compile the kernel does not match the version of the compiler I have. `11.4.0` but the installer insists on `11.3.0`.

**How can I install the required version of gcc?**

kubuntu: `22.04` with kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux aero 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Kernel Compiler Version:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.2.0-26-generic (buildd@bos03-amd64-042) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2
```

Installed gcc version:

```
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

Graphics card version:

```
sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER]
```

Comment: If you are wanting to use older *kernel modules*, why not switch to use the GA kernel stack?  Your 6.2 kernel shows you're using HWE, but 5.15 is the GA stack; did you explore that option (*an easier option I'm sure*).

Answer (score 2):

This is not recommended but you can install version 11.3 by downloading [gcc-11 (version 11.3) from here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/gcc-11/download). And downloading the dependencies [gcc-11-base](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/gcc-11-base/download) and [libgcc-11-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libgcc-11-dev/download).

Then, run `sudo apt install /path/to/file` where `/path/to/file` is the path to the actual downloaded file. If it can't find the file, you may need to put it in double quotes like `"/path/to/file"`.

You will need to install the `gcc-11-base` package first, then `libgcc-11-dev` and finally, `gcc-11`.

For example, if it's downloaded to your Downloads directory:

```
sudo apt install $HOME/Downloads/gcc-11-base_11.3.0-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and

```
sudo apt install $HOME/Downloads/libgcc-11-dev_11.3.0-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and

```
sudo apt install $HOME/Downloads/gcc-11_11.3.0-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I'm pretty sure `gcc` only requires gcc-11 >11.2 so this should downgrade your version of gcc and when you're done compiling or whatever you need it for, simply run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-11 gcc-11-base libgcc-11-dev
```

to upgrade back to the current version of gcc-11 (11.4).

Granted, the installation isn't guaranteed to work, could be insecure or lacking security updates. Also, you may run into dependency issues. If that's the case, you'd have to tread carefully or install each dependency one by one but **always pay attention to what, if any, packages would need to uninstall when installing weird versions because you don't want to inadvertently uninstall a bunch of stuff you want or need.**

---

### EDIT: you will need to install dependencies (included above) but you can run the following commands to do it more quickly.

Run the following commands to create a working directory and download the packages:

```
cd
mkdir GCC11.3
cd GCC11.3
wget 'http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-11/gcc-11-base_11.3.0-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb'
wget 'http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-11/libgcc-11-dev_11.3.0-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb'
wget 'http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-11/gcc-11_11.3.0-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb'
```

Now, install the packages. **Again, however, remember to pay attention to what, if any packages will be uninstalled when you install these weird versions. Review the list before you select Y to accept the changes!**:

```
sudo apt install ./gcc*.deb
```

And again, when you're done compiling or whatever you need gcc 11.3 for, simply run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-11 gcc-11-base libgcc-dev
```

to upgrade back to gcc 11.4.